# Redirect www.site.com/feeds to www.site.com/Layouts/feeds.html, keeping the url intact?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Suppose user goes to `www.site.com/feeds`. It must show `www.site.com/Layouts/feeds.html`, keeping the url intact. How to do that with .htaccess?

**Failure**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site\.com/feeds$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/Layouts/feeds.html [R=301,L]
```

**404 with this?! [contacted my admin about this, second, maybe a system thing]**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/feeds$ index.html [P]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's an htaccess file, the context path is stripped; remove the leading slashes.

```
RewriteRule ^feeds$ Layouts/feeds.html [L]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to "keep the URL intact", then you're not issuing a redirect, by definition -- a redirect is an instruction to the web browser "please go request this other page".

Instead, what you want is the Proxy flag to your `RewriteRule`, something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/feeds$ http://www.site.com/Layout/Feeds.html [P]
```

Comment: @womble `[P]` should just be for external proxying - doesn't work for internal.

Comment: Also - good to see you, welcome back!

Comment: @hhh Have you gotten rid of that bad `RewriteCond`? What's the config look like now?